# How to simulate click/tap in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I am writing a test in Codename One, in which I want to simulate click anywhere on the screen, since I want to check that a certain dialog is hidden. I tried to simulate the click using press and release:

```
form.pointerPressed(2, 2);
form.pointerReleased(2, 2);
```

But it did not work in the tests, nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pointerPressed` and `pointerReleased`, but not called on the form, but on the `Display`, was the correct thing to do. I guess that the form I was trying to click was not accessible because of the blocking dialog.

```
Display.getInstance().pointerPressed(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can cause that.

- That specific dialog might not be dismissible with pointer out of bounds touch.
- That point might be problematic for some reason e.g. might be in the status bar
- The dialog might still be showing since the EDT needs to be flushed with callSerially
- The code might not be reachable since the dialog blocked some execution due to `invokeAndBlock`